# Why morphological opening displace my image?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a picure from a microscope. I want to quantify the number of cellular nucli (blue ovals - see picture original image)

For that I am using Python 2.7 with OpenCV3.

First, I load the image in BGR, and extract the blue layer

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg',1)
img_gray = img[:,:,0]
```

Next, I produce the BINARY image and then I applied morphological opening, filling and measured contours (see picture: GRAY-after thresholding, OP-n:after opening n times, 'filling holes' and measuring contours.

```
_, img_thres =  cv2.threshold(img_gray, 40, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

For iterations=2 see upper panels (OP-2)

```
kernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)
img_op = cv2.morphologyEx(img_thres, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations =2)
```

or

For iterations=20 see bottom panels (OP-20)

```
img_op = cv2.morphologyEx(img_thres, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations =20)
```

For simplicity I am skiping the filling and contours code.

You can see how the contours are shifted, they  shift to the right proportionality to the number of iterations during the opening transformation.

Opening should remove background pixels, as it is doing, but not shift the pixels. What is going on? 
[image: Opening Issues]

****EDIT****

> didnt verify it, but maybe it's because your kernel is of even size?
>   try an odd kernel size please like 3 or 5. – Micka

You are right!
See pictures (both opening iterations=20):

[image]

Comment: didnt verify it, but maybe it's because your kernel is of even size? try an odd kernel size please like 3 or 5.

Comment: That's it! but how come? how did you even thought about this? Could you explain why? I will edit with pictures

Comment: @Micka I am with you!

Comment: with an even kernel size you dont have a real "center" pixel, so the operation probably "prefers" one direction.

Comment: Just to add, for example Gaussian kernel has a sinusoidal nature so odd number would better represent symmetry at the peak value , the "center" pixel.

Comment: @RickM Not sure about the meaning of a Gaussian Kernel. Could you please explain me or add a link to understand how to use a Gaussian Kernel. I search online, should I get it with: cv2.getGaussianKernel?